# Condition for two events to be independent

Tags: probability

**Question:**

> An experiment has 10 equally likely outcomes. Let $A$ and $B$ be two
>   non-empty events of that experiment. If $A$ consists of $4$ outcomes,
>   find the number that $B$ must have in order for $A$ and $B$ to be
>   independent.

I really don't understand what the question is asking. For two events to be independent, the probability of one of the events occurring must be independent of the other event occurring. So shouldn't the answer simply be $6$?

Comment: Recall the [definition of independence of events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Two_events).

Comment: I would say "at most 6".

Comment: @user247327 See, that's incorrect as well. That's why I got even more confused....

Comment: @Gummybears The probability of $A$ is $\Pr[A]=[\dots]$. If $B$ contains $n$ outcomes, with $k\leq \min(4,n)$ become common with $A$, then $\Pr[A]=[\dots]$ and $\Pr[A\cap B]=[\dots]$. So what are the settings of $n,k$ that make independence (as per the definition linked above) possible?

Comment: The easy outcome is half of the A outcomes and half of the non-A outcomes.

Comment: @almagest I really don't get how we get that. Would you mind explaining it a bit more?

Comment: You want the prob of $A$ and $B$ to be the same as the prob of $A$ and not $B$.

Comment: @Gummybears Read kccu's answer or my comment(s). You need $0\leq k \leq \min(n,4)\leq 10$ satisfying $\frac{4}{10}\cdot\frac{n}{10} = \frac{k}{10}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're confusing *independent* with *mutually exclusive*. Events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Events $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive if $A \cap B = \varnothing$, i.e., whenever one of $A$ or $B$ occurs, the other does not.

This problem asks you to determine what the number of outcomes in $B$ must be in order to have $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Since the experiment has $10$ equally likely outcomes,

\begin{align*}
P(A \cap B)= \frac{|A \cap B|}{10},\ P(A)=\frac{|A|}{10}=\frac{4}{10}, \ P(B)=\frac{|B|}{10}.
\end{align*}

The equation $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ then becomes $\frac{|A\cap B|}{10}=\frac{4}{10}\cdot \frac{|B|}{10}$, or $5\cdot |A\cap B|=2 \cdot |B|$. What are the possible values of $|B|$ that could satisfy this equation?

Comment: Aha... I get it up till here... But I don't get how we would proceed on... Writing out individual cases? Or is there a better method?

Comment: This gives $2n = 5k$, writing $k=\lvert A\cap B\rvert$ and $n=\lvert B\rvert$. Since you also have $k \leq \min(n,4)$ and $n\leq 10$, the fact that $2n=5k$ leaves few options (in particular, $k$ has to be even, so $k\in \{0,2,4\}$). Check all 3 cases to see what happens.

Comment: @Gummybears Yes, there are only a few cases to check, and as Clement C. points out you can rule some out pretty easily. Perhaps it's useful to note that $|B|$ must be divisible by $5$, which leaves just three possibilities to check.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!